# Angular2 multiple components different imports

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-modules

I am pretty new to Angular2, and i'm trying to modify a template.
Basically, by default, all views are nested in a template with Header, Footer and TopNavbarModule.

I am trying to avoid importing these modules for some view components.

So I have built my `blank.component` and imported it in `app.module` but I am still importing the 3 view modules I don't want in `app.module`, otherwise they would not be imported at all (neither for the "blank" pages, or "other" pages).

I think that maybe I have to declare another `NgModule` in `app.module` or creating a separate blank.module - any ideas?

Definition of `app.module`

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {BlankComponent} from "./blank.component";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {ROUTES} from "./app.routes";
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

// App views
import {MainViewModule} from "../views/main-view/main-view.module";
import {DashboardViewModule} from "../views/dashboard-view/dashboard-view.module";

// App modules/components
import {NavigationModule} from "../views/common/navigation/navigation.module";
import {FooterModule} from "../views/common/footer/footer.module";
import {TopnavbarModule} from "../views/common/topnavbar/topnavbar.module";
import {LoginViewModule} from "../views/login-view/login-view.module";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, BlankComponent],
    imports     : [

        // Angular modules
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,

        // Views
        MainViewModule,
        DashboardViewModule,
        LoginViewModule,

        // Modules
        NavigationModule,
        FooterModule,
        TopnavbarModule,

        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
    ],
    providers   : [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap   : [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Definition of `blank.component`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { correctHeight, detectBody } from './app.helpers';

// Core vendor styles
import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import '../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
import '../../node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css'

// Main Inspinia CSS files
import '../../src/assets/styles/style.css'

declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
    selector   : 'blank',
    templateUrl: 'blank.template.html',
})

export class BlankComponent {

}
```

Comment: What do you want BlankComponent be used for?

Re: modules, you might find the [module guidance](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-module-recommendations) useful to determine which modules you want/need.

Comment: I want it to be used for avoiding loading NavigationModule, FooterModule and TopnavbarModule,

Comment: Ah ok, so it's like a 'home component' that frames the page - and you then load a view based on route e.g. /main, /dashboard or /login ?

Comment: Exactly, I already have an AppComponent, but it looks like it inheritaes from the AppModule that loads the unecessary Modules

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `MainViewModule`, `DasboardViewModule` and `LoginViewModule` are feature modules so I'd probably structure it like below:

- `AppModule`
- `HomeModule` - I'd have navigation, topnavbar, and footer components all defined in a single module, then import this into `AppModule`.  You could keep the 3 separate modules if you like but I'm not sure what you gain from that.
- Then in `app.routing' you can lazy load those 'view' modules as required.

..

```
 const appRoute: Routes = [
       path: '',
       component: BlankComponent,
       children: [
         { 
            path: 'main',
            loadChildren: 'app/views/main-view/main-view.module#MainViewModule'
         },
         { 
            path: 'login',
            loadChildren: 'app/views/login-view/login-view.module#LoginViewModule'
         }
         { 
            path: 'dashboard',
            loadChildren: 'app/views/dashboard-view/dashboard-view.module#DashboardViewModule'
         }
       ]
]
```

The template for BlankComponent (defined in app.module) would be the only place using the top-nav/footer components and providing a `router-outlet` where the 'view' would be displayed. Something like this:

`<app-top-nav></app-top-nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>`

The `AppModule` imports are minimal:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //Angular modules
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    CoreModule, //your module containing services (see module guidance)
    SharedModule, //your modules with commons pipes, directives etc (see module guidance)
    HomeModule, //your module contains the navbar, footer etc
    routing
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, BlankComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The feature (view) modules would then only be importing a `SharedModule` if they used common components, along with any Angular module dependencies.  I typically have the `SharedModule` re-export common Angular dependencies like the forms module, so that consumers of the `SharedModule` don't need to remember to  import those every time.

Not sure if that is exactly what you had in mind, but hopefully it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your complete answer, I've pushed a [repository](https://github.com/adrien3d/ang2-base-front) containing my src file, it would be amazing if you could open a PR containing modifications you consider usefull